# What are the possible causes for a tail light that comes on when bumped?

Tags: lights

I took my car to the dealer to have some recall work done. He mentioned that some of the lights on the car were out including the license plate light and the driver side tail light. When examining the car myself, I bumped the tail light and it came on. Same with the plate light.

Is this a sign of just some loose bulbs, catastrophically expensive wiring issues, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a loose bulb, corrosion in the socket, or most probably a filament which is going bad. I doubt it's anything catastrophically expensive to fix. Easiest first try is to just pull the bulb and look for corrosion in the socket. Next see if the filament wiggles inside the bulb. If all else fails, just replace the bulb with a new one. If none of this works, you'll probably have to take it to a shop to have it looked at.

Comment: I agree but would like to add one little detail: if car has multiple electronic components with corrosion damage, check fuse box and any other visible places for corossion. I have seen cars that had been transported over salty seas and therefore had corossion in places where there should never be any.